# Using LINQ, how can I cast a List<object> to a List<SelectListItem> in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to render a dropdown list of users, and am having difficulty casting a list of user objects to a List.  Various attempts that I've tried include using .ToList() and .Cast, but these have failed as noted below.

Here is my present method.

```
public static List<SelectListItem> getStandardDropdownList(EnumStatusIsActive.StatusIsActive statusIsActive, UserListValueType userListValueType)
{
    List<SelectListItemUser> userList = Shared.getDataForStandardDropdownListItemUser(UserListType.ExternalUser, statusIsActive, null);
    List<SelectListItem> standardList = userList.Select(u => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = u.UserName,
        Value = u.UserToken.ToString()
    });
}
```

Where this fails is at userList.Select().  The error message for the above is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

So I attempted .ToList(), as follows. But that resulted in the same error.

```
List<SelectListItem> standardList = userList.ToList().Select(u => new SelectListItem ...
```

And I tried using Cast, like so ...

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItemUser> userCollection = Shared.getDataForStandardDropdownListItemUser(UserListType.ExternalUser, statusIsActive, null);
List<SelectListItem> standardList = userCollection.Cast<SelectListItemUser>().Select(u => new SelectListItem ...
```

Still no love, and the same error message.  Now I can iterate through the list via a for/each loop to create the necessary `List<SelectListItem>`, but I'd prefer to do this via Linq.  What change do I need to make to get this working?  Thanks!

Comment: Correct way is `Select(...).ToList()`. So you got it almost right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ToList()` call goes at the end:

```
List<SelectListItem> standardList = userList.Select(u => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = u.UserName,
    Value = u.UserToken.ToString()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you both!  Works like a champ.

Answer (score 3):

You were close. Select is the right approach, you just need to do a ToList() AFTER not before the Select. :]

Comment: Please select Stuartd's answer as he made it first :]